# I want SqlCommand to return nothing, just do

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sqlcommand

I have a stored procedure that does a lot of stuff based on if the person's password fits the criteria. I don't need it to return anything. Just execute the procedure.

I was looking at [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) and it seems all of the `Execute(blah)` extensions return something. Is there an `Execute(blah)` for `SqlCommand` that just executes the procedure and doesn't return anything?

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery()` will just return the number of rows affected which you can ignore.  Feedback loops are generally a Good Thing.

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` will execute query and return amount of affected rows. You can call this method without assigning return value. just `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: I was actually using that.  Okay.  Excellent!  Thank you

Comment: I didn't know if there was a better option or if ExecuteNonQuery was the best.  Thank you

Comment: If one of you would like to make it an answer, I'll give it a check

Comment: You can use `ExecuteScalar` too. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I was looking at that one too.  One returns the row and one returns an int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx). It will return the number of rows affected, just don't assign it.

```
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING"))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("YOUR PROCEDURE NAME", conn))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for the "SET NOCOUNT" statement.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189837.aspx

It prevents Transactions and Stored procedures from returning the extra messages about what it did.

Comment: website not found

Comment: try again, should be sorted now.

Comment: so that goes inside my SP. interesting